# No sound in headphones. After change in mixer no saved setting

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Haven't sound at front output and have sound only rear side

In mixer stand mute at headphones for default and no saved, after changes and reboot

```
ProblemType: Bug
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 16.04
Package: alsa-base 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5
ProcVersionSignature: Ubuntu 4.4.0-22.40-generic 4.4.8
Uname: Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64
NonfreeKernelModules: nvidia_uvm nvidia
ApportVersion: 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1
Architecture: amd64
AudioDevicesInUse:
 USER PID ACCESS COMMAND
 /dev/snd/controlC1: kirill 1684 F.... pulseaudio
 /dev/snd/controlC0: kirill 1684 F.... pulseaudio
CurrentDesktop: Unity
Date: Sat Jun 4 23:51:09 2016
InstallationDate: Installed on 2016-06-04 (0 days ago)
InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" - Release amd64 (20160420.1)
PackageArchitecture: all
ProcEnviron:
 LANGUAGE=ru
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
 LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
 SHELL=/bin/bash
SourcePackage: alsa-driver
Symptom: audio
Symptom_AlsaPlaybackTest: ALSA playback test through plughw:PCH failed
Symptom_Card: ?????????? ????? - HDA Intel PCH
Symptom_Jack: Green Headphone Out, Front
Symptom_Type: Only some of outputs are working
Title: [MS-7817, Realtek ALC887-VD, Green Headphone Out, Front] Playback problem
UpgradeStatus: No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)
dmi.bios.date: 04/21/2015
dmi.bios.vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
dmi.bios.version: V6.7
dmi.board.asset.tag: To be filled by O.E.M.
dmi.board.name: H81M-E33 (MS-7817)
dmi.board.vendor: MSI
dmi.board.version: 1.0
dmi.chassis.asset.tag: To be filled by O.E.M.
dmi.chassis.type: 3
dmi.chassis.vendor: MSI
dmi.chassis.version: 1.0
dmi.modalias: dmi:bvnAmericanMegatrendsInc.:bvrV6.7:bd04/21/2015:svnMSI:pnMS-7817:pvr1.0:rvnMSI:rnH81M-E33(MS-7817):rvr1.0:cvnMSI:ct3:cvr1.0:
dmi.product.name: MS-7817
dmi.product.version: 1.0
dmi.sys.vendor: MSI
```

In 14.04.4 all was normal.